# Symfony 2 - entity repository - accesing entity data from repository

Tags: symfony

I have `user entity` with custom repository for it. I have created an event listener to check if given user is authorized to access given game account.

To this I have created custom function `hasAccountOfId($id)` in my user repository. However I have problem with accessing this function from the event listener.

**User entity:**

```
 /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
    /.../

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $accounts;
```

**User entity custom repository**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * UserRepository
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function hasAccountOfId($accountId)
    {
            foreach ($this->accounts as $account) {
                if ($account.id ==  $accountId) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

And **the listener** where I am struggling with accessing `hasAccountOfId` function.

```
// Account is set, verify if user is authorized
            $id = $this->session->get("accountId");
            $user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
            $userEm = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
            if(!$user->hasAccountOfId($id))
            {
                // Not authorized
                die("Not authorized");
            }
```

returns:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "hasAccountOfId" of class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\User".

while using `!$userEm->hasAccountOfId($id)` results in:

> Notice: Undefined property: AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository::$accounts

How may I access my user repository for `$user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()` ?

Comment: Check the docs for repository classes http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: Thanks for clue, I have created the repository according to this documentation but my problem is connected with accessing this repository based on user information received from $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser().

Comment: The error says that there is undefined property `$accounts` in the repository class. You need to write query that will check if provided ID exists. Check `DQL` docs http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: I want to access in this function $accounts from class User. Should I pass "user object (user entity)" to "entity repository"? Or maybe there is a function that gives me access to repository of a given entity?

Comment: Yes, just pass user entity or its ID to the function. You already you have access to the repository class `$userEm`, this is the right way to access entity's repository class.

Comment: Maybe it will be wiser to transfer public function hasAccountOfId($accountId) to entity class than? What do you recommend?

Comment: Doctrine entities are just entities that only contain data, not handles it. So repositories is the right place for such methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly for this simple [OneToMany](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) association You need to provide the `Owning` side of relation (in `Account` class). By creating new `Account` for `User` You will need to call `$account->setUser($user);` to make the `Relation`.
2. Secondly You don't need a custom method in Your `RepositoryClass` as You will get Accounts from Doctrine's Relation: `$user->getAccounts()`.
3. The iteration through the `Accounts` to look for `ID` should be done NOT in `RepositoryClass` or `Entity` itself, but using a `Manager Service` or something else, because other way will violate `Singe Responsibility Principle`.

And finally, there is no `.` for class properties or methods, it must be `->`. Note `if` statement in `hasAccountOfId` method.